# How can i get status of workflow via rest api - whant to know when its completed,failed etc

Tags: javascript, rest, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

Is there a way i can get the status of my running workflow for a particular record?
I; working on a form that has a submit button and would like to enable it only when the status of the workflow is complete.
Any ideas

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternate, you may use the below javascript code:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWorkflowStatus, "sp.js");  
var listTitle = 'Tutorial';  
var listItemId = 1;  
var workflowTitle = 'Approval';  

function getWorkflowStatus()  
{  
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
  var web = context.get_web();  
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);  
  var listItem = list.getItemById(listItemId);     
  context.load(listItem);  
  context.executeQueryAsync(  
     function() {  
       var workflowStatusField = listItem.get_parentList().get_fields().getByTitle(workflowTitle); //get workflow status field  
       var workflowStatusValue = listItem.get_item(workflowTitle); //get workflow status field value  
       console.log('Approval is completed');  
     },  
    function(sender,args){  
   console.log(args.get_message());  
     }  
  );  
}
```

[Source](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013-get-workflow-status-programatically-using-jsom)